# I am trying to transfer a file from oracle VirtualBox in my computer to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to transfer a file from oracle VirtualBox in my computer to AWS EC2 instance

used command -

```
scp /progs/add.sh root@18.221.48.189:/file1
```

where - 18.221.48.189 is public IP of AWS instance

I am receiving the below error please help

```
The authenticity of host '18.221.48.189 (18.221.48.189)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:g6AQEO7IYb8rqIb12+JCnwmYVISyfAT6Of2sLLhq4r4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '18.221.48.189' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Comment: You didn't do a key exchange? I assume you have to that first.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ssh and scp use the default id_rsa key to authenticate and it looks like your EC2 instance is using a different ssh key.

You need to specify what ssh key using `-i /path/to/ssh_key`

`scp -i ssh_key /progs/add.sh root@18.221.48.189:/file1`

EDIT: Formatting

Answer (score 0):

What Linux is running on your EC2 Instance?  You may need to use the user name "ec2-user" for the connection.

```
scp /progs/add.sh ec2-user@18.221.48.189:/file1
```

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

Get the default user name for the AMI that you used to launch your instance:

- For Amazon Linux 2 or the Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is ec2-user.
- For a CentOS AMI, the user name is centos.
- For a Debian AMI, the user name is admin.
- For a Fedora AMI, the user name is ec2-user or fedora.
- For a RHEL AMI, the user name is ec2-user or root.
- For a SUSE AMI, the user name is ec2-user or root.
- For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is ubuntu.
- Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don't work, check with the AMI provider.